Why am I getting 8 error bars for each datapoint on this plot in R?
I am trying to make a plot in R containing the average Pb isotope ratios(206Pb/207Pb and 208Pb/207Pb) from 2 sites ("control" and "activesite"). I want 4 error bars on each data point (site) showing the standard deviation. I already calculated the average and standard deviation in excel so instead of pasting all of my data I have just listed the averages as "avg206Pb207Pb" and standard deviations as "sd206Pb207Pb". This code has previously run just fine on my other data but for some reason I am now getting 8 error bars for each data point. Additionally usually the error bars will have perpendicular lines at the end of them and these don't. What am I missing here?
Data:
|site         |avg206Pb207Pb |sd206Pb207Pb |avg208Pb207Pb|sd208Pb207Pb|
|active site  |1.2553        |0.0046       |2.5245        |0.0017     |
|control      |1.2476        |0.0021       |2.5254        |0.0027     |

Code:
pbratiofourwayerror$site <- factor(
  pbratiofourwayerror$site, 
  levels = c("activesite","control")
)

a <- ggplot(
  pbratiofourwayerror, 
  aes(x=avg208Pb207Pb, y=avg206Pb207Pb)
) + 
geom_point(
  aes(color=site, shape=site), 
  size=5
) + 
scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,19)) +
xlab(expression(""^208*"Pb"*"/"^"207"*Pb)) + 
ylab(expression(""^206*"Pb"*"/"^"207"*Pb)) + 
theme_classic() + 
geom_errorbarh(
  aes(
    xmax = avg208Pb207Pb + sd208Pb207Pb, 
    xmin = avg208Pb207Pb - sd208Pb207Pb, 
    color=site
  ), 
  height=0.25
) + 
geom_errorbar(
  aes(
    ymin=avg206Pb207Pb-sd206Pb207Pb, 
    ymax=avg206Pb207Pb+sd206Pb207Pb, 
    color=site
  ), 
  width=0.25
)

a


hi, can you use dput(data.frame) to make it easier for us to look at your data to trouble shoot?

Seconding @cianius to include raw data. Why not let R do the calculation & visualisation of your data including error bars? Also: mean +- sd is an odd way to calculate & show error bars. What are these error bars supposed to denote?

Stack overflow wouldn't let me post tables or pictures at the time because I didn't have enought reputation points. Anyways it ended up being the height and width size. Thanks  for your help though!

I simplified your dataset a little for a minimal reproducible example. Your geom_errobar()/geom_errobarh() width/height are way too high for this dataset.
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.3.2
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 4.3.2


data  = tibble ( site = c("a","c"), 
                  avg1 =c(1.25, 1.24),
                 sd1 = c(0.0046, 0.021), 
                  avg2 = c(2.52, 2.56),
                 sd2 = c(0.0017,0.0027))

 ggplot(
  data, 
  aes(x=avg1, y=avg2)
) + 
  geom_point(
    aes(color=site, shape=site), 
    size=5
  ) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,19)) +
  xlab(expression(""^208*"Pb"*"/"^"207"*Pb)) + 
  ylab(expression(""^206*"Pb"*"/"^"207"*Pb)) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_errorbarh(
    aes(
      xmax = avg1 + sd1, 
      xmin = avg1 - sd1, 
      color=site
    ),#
   height=0.001
  ) + 
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(
      ymin=avg2-sd2, 
      ymax=avg2+sd2, 
      color=site
    ), 
    width=0.001
  )


Created on 2024-04-29 with reprex v2.0.2

Thanks! It was the width and height. Stackoverflow wouldn't let me post pictures or the data set because I didn't have enough reputation points.

@MeganReaves, see how I posted a dataset data as an example that everyone could reproduce in R. You can do something like that next time, as other already pointed out.  Posting a picture of dataset is really not suggested.
